# Boxplots with multiple categories with seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

This should be really easy but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Here is a sample of my dataframe.

[image]
\n

`sns.boxplot(x='dataset', y='value', hue='Model', data=dd)`

but I get this error

`ValueError: List of boxplot statistics and`positions`values must have same the length`

Comment: you want a factorplot: `seaborn.factorplot(x='dataset', y='value', hue='Model', data=dd, kind='box')`

Comment: Also getting the same problem.  Was this ever resolved?

Comment: Just figured out my error.  My series types were objects instead of floats.  Once I converted those with .astype(float), it worked.

Comment: You can easily check this with the command: `df.dtypes`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments you want to convert your data to floats

```
dd['value'] = dd['value'].astype(float)
sns.boxplot(x='dataset', y='value', hue='Model', data=dd)
```

Should work for you